# RegEx for MyString then one or more CRLFs and zero or more lines with anything then MyString2

Tags: regex, groovy

RegEx to make sure a config file has some preferred settings in it.
My human language is this:

ntp one {1 or more CRLF and any characters} ntp two|ntp two {1 or more CRLF and any chars} ntp one

As a start I'm trying to test it with RegEx101.com but the final usage is in groovy.

It must match all these possibilities below:

case #1

```
ntp one
ntp two
```

---

case 2:

```
anything
ntp one
ntp two
```

---

case 3:

```
ntp one
1 or more lines of anything
ntp two
```

---

case 4:

```
ntp two
ntp one
```

---

case 5:

```
ntp two
1 or more lines of anything
ntp one
```

---

case 6:

```
ntp one
1 or more lines of anything
ntp two
1 or more lines with whatever
```

---

In contrast, it should not match this:

```
ntp ten
ntp eleven
```

my feeble as my attempts are...

```
ntp one[\s\S]ntp two|ntp two[\s\S]ntp one and ntp one.*ntp two|ntp two.*ntp one.  I don't know WHY this doesn't work - but I have very basic RegEx skills.
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: yes...feeble as my attempts are....
ntp one[\s\S]ntp two|ntp two[\s\S]ntp one and ntp one.*ntp two|ntp two.*ntp one

Comment: @user2274586 post all relevant information in your question so that we can see what you've tried and explain why it doesn't work. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It also helps if you don't start your question with "I need" and instead with explaining the issue in a very detailed and concise manner. To quote the article I've linked to: **Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague**.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give this a shot:

```
(ntp one\n(.*?)ntp two)|(ntp two\n(.*?)ntp one)
```

It's pretty much saying what you wrote out.

- start with ntp one
- have a new line
- anything is fine, bunch of whatever lines (or none)
- end with ntp two

OR

- start with ntp two
- have a new line
- anything is fine, , bunch of whatever lines (or none)
- end with ntp one

Here is a working example in Python:

```
import re

theregex = re.compile("(ntp one\n(.*?)ntp two)|(ntp two\n(.*?)ntp one)", re.DOTALL)
thestring = '''ntp one
1 or more lines of anything
ntp two'''

if re.search(theregex, thestring):
    print ("match")
```

Depending on the actual implementation you'll need to make use of DOTALL modifier with your language.  This will make . (DOT) match newlines.  You'll note here I have that turned on:

https://regex101.com/r/MkfNPw/1

Comment: hmm. that didn't work on RegEx101.com  for 
    ntp one
    any
    ntp two

Comment: Thanks for the help. It still doesn't seem to work for case #2 or #6 shown in question. (I numbered the cases and added #6.)

Comment: I've updated the regex for case #2 and #6.  I removed the ^ and $ characters